# Can i shut down my PC once EBS snapshot process is initiated through AWS Dashboard?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk, amazon-ebs

I am new to the Amazon Cloud. I need to take a EBS snapshot of 150 GB data and I am on a metered bandwidth (say 30 GB/month). I am aware EBS snapshots take few hours to complete.

I need to know whether I can log off the Amazon dashboard and shut down my PC once I trigger the snapshot creation process through AWS Dashboard OR should my PC be kept turned ON during the entire process. Does it require my system to be connected to the internet until snapshot creation process is complete? My PC runs on a metered bandwidth and hence this query...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to keep your computer on when performing this kind of operation. The snapshot creation is handled by AWS servers.

Unless you are uploading or downloading large portions of data to and from AWS (which is not your case), you do not need to be connected to the infrastructure at all after you submit the request.